# moving buckets and birth/death count

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have a pandas dataframe of this type (minimal example):

```
myDf = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A'','B', 'C', 'D', 'E']*2,'date': ['2017-05-25']*5+['2017-05-26']*5,'nVisits':[10,2,3,0,0,6,0,4,8,1]})
```

In table looks like:

```
date        nVisits user
5/25/2017   10      A
5/25/2017   2       B
5/25/2017   3       C
5/25/2017   0       D
5/25/2017   0       E
5/26/2017   6       A
5/26/2017   0       B
5/26/2017   4       C
5/26/2017   8       D
5/26/2017   1       E
```

(1) I would like to categorize my users everyday into, let us say, 4 buckets: 0 visits, 1 visit, 2-4 visits, 5+visits so I want to create a summary of the dataframe that looks like this:

```
date        group      nVisits  nObs
5/25/2017   zero       0        2
5/25/2017   one        0        0
5/25/2017   twoToFour  2        2
5/25/2017   fivePlus   10       1
5/26/2017   zero       0        1
5/26/2017   one        1        1
5/26/2017   twoToFour  4        1
5/26/2017   fivePlus   16       2
```

This dataframe is basically the number of observations per bucket as well as the number of visits per bucket, where which users belong to which bucket gets updatd daily.

(2) I'd want to catalog all births and death's of clients, where a birth is categorized as a client that went from 0 visits to >1 visits, and a death as a client that went from >1 visit to 0 visit.

In this specific example the new dataframe would look like this:

```
date        event_type  user    nVisitsAtBirthDeath
5/26/2017   death       B       2
5/26/2017   birth       D       8
5/26/2017   birth       E       1
```

This dataframe is basically the comparison from today to previous day in terms of which users went from 0 visit to more or equal to 1 visit, and which users went from more or equal to 1 visit to 0 visit.

Could you help me getting started on how to do this in an efficient and performant manner.  My original dataframe is relatively big so doing for loop in python runs too slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [29]: df['group'] = pd.cut(df.nVisits,
                              [-1, 0, 1, 4, np.inf], 
                              labels=['zero','one','twoToFour','fivePlus'])

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
         date  nVisits user      group
0  2017-05-25       10    A   fivePlus
1  2017-05-25        2    B  twoToFour
2  2017-05-25        3    C  twoToFour
3  2017-05-25        0    D       zero
4  2017-05-25        0    E       zero
5  2017-05-26        6    A   fivePlus
6  2017-05-26        0    B       zero
7  2017-05-26        4    C  twoToFour
8  2017-05-26        8    D   fivePlus
9  2017-05-26        1    E        one
```

Comment: I like this a lot!

Comment: @Dnaiel, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use np.where()

myDf['group'] = np.where(myDf.nVisits > 5, 'fiveplus', np.where(myDf.nVisits == 0, 'zero', 
np.where(myDf.nVisits ==1, 'one', 'twotofour')))

```
    date        nVisits user    group
0   2017-05-25  10      A       fiveplus
1   2017-05-25  2       B       twotofour
2   2017-05-25  3       C       twotofour
3   2017-05-25  0       D       zero
4   2017-05-25  0       E       zero
5   2017-05-26  6       A       fiveplus
6   2017-05-26  0       B       zero
7   2017-05-26  4       C       twotofour
8   2017-05-26  8       D       fiveplus
9   2017-05-26  1       E       one
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1:

```
df1 = myDf.assign(group=pd.cut(myDf.nVisits,[0,1,2,5,np.inf],right=False,labels=['zero','one','twotoFour','fivePlus']))
```

Output:

```
         date  nVisits user      group
0  2017-05-25       10    A   fivePlus
1  2017-05-25        2    B  twotoFour
2  2017-05-25        3    C  twotoFour
3  2017-05-25        0    D       zero
4  2017-05-25        0    E       zero
5  2017-05-26        6    A   fivePlus
6  2017-05-26        0    B       zero
7  2017-05-26        4    C  twotoFour
8  2017-05-26        8    D   fivePlus
9  2017-05-26        1    E        one

df2 = df1.groupby(['date','group']).agg({'nVisits':'sum','user':'count'}).reset_index()

print(df2)

         date      group  user  nVisits
0  2017-05-25   fivePlus     1       10
1  2017-05-25  twotoFour     2        5
2  2017-05-25       zero     2        0
3  2017-05-26   fivePlus     2       14
4  2017-05-26        one     1        1
5  2017-05-26  twotoFour     1        4
6  2017-05-26       zero     1        0
```

## Solution 2:

```
df2 = df1.assign(nVisitsAtBirthDeath=df1.groupby('user').filter(lambda x: x.nVisits.eq(0).any()).groupby('user')['nVisits'].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift())).dropna()

df3 = df2.assign(event=np.where(df2.nVisitsAtBirthDeath<0,'Death','Birth'))

print(df3)
```

Output:

```
         date  nVisits user     group  nVisitsAtBirthDeath  event
6  2017-05-26        0    B      zero                 -2.0  Death
8  2017-05-26        8    D  fivePlus                  8.0  Birth
9  2017-05-26        1    E       one                  1.0  Birth
```

Answer (score 1):

1.
solution for the first item

```
def label(visits):
    if visits == 0:
        return 'zero'
    if visits == 1:
        return 'one'
    if visits < 5:
        return 'twoToFour'
    return 'fivePlus'
myDf['group'] = myDf['nVisits'].apply(label)
```

2.
Solution for the second item

```
myDf['last_day_visits'] = myDf.groupby('user').nVisits.shift(1).fillna(0)
def event_type(row):
    if row['nVisits'] > 0 and row['last_day_visits'] == 0:
        return 'birth'
    if row['nVisits'] == 0 and row['last_day_visits'] > 0:
        return 'death'

myDf['event_type'] = myDf.apply(event_type, axis=1)
```